# Nextjs middlware matcher without index url

Tags: middleware

First, please excuse that English is not my first language.

I want to set middle for without index url.
I tried like the code but it didn't work.
(Without session, I wanted to push user to index page)
Any Idea?

```
export const config = {
    matcher:"/([^/.].*)"
}
```